# Order by max value on distinct records, without using a subquery (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+-----------+--------+------+--------+----------+----------+---------+-------+
| player_id | europe | asia | africa | namerica | lamerica | oceania | total |
+-----------+--------+------+--------+----------+----------+---------+-------+
|    121693 |   1076 | 70   | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |  1146 |
|    121693 |    416 | 70   | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |   486 |
|    121693 |     40 | NULL | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |    40 |
|    118840 |     40 | NULL | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |    40 |
|    121693 |     40 | 70   | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |   110 |
|    118840 |     40 | 490  | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |   530 |
|    121691 |     96 | 0    | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |    96 |
|    121693 |    136 | 70   | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |   206 |
|    118840 |     40 | NULL | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |    40 |
|    121691 |     96 | NULL | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |    96 |
+-----------+--------+------+--------+----------+----------+---------+-------+
```

What I would like to get is something like:

```
+-----------+--------+------+--------+----------+----------+---------+-------+
| player_id | europe | asia | africa | namerica | lamerica | oceania | total |
+-----------+--------+------+--------+----------+----------+---------+-------+
|    121693 |   1076 |   70 | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |  1146 |
|    118840 |     40 |  490 | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |   530 |
|    121691 |     96 |    0 | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |    96 |
+-----------+--------+------+--------+----------+----------+---------+-------+
```

I have tried the following, but the results are not quite what I need.

```
SELECT player_id, europe, asia, africa, namerica, 
                lamerica, oceania, MAX(total) AS total 
FROM tbl 
WHERE total IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY player_id 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

this is the result

```
+-----------+--------+------+--------+----------+----------+---------+-------+
| player_id | europe | asia | africa | namerica | lamerica | oceania | total |
+-----------+--------+------+--------+----------+----------+---------+-------+
|    121693 |   1076 |   70 | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |  1146 |
|    118840 |     40 |      | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |   530 |
|    121691 |     96 |    0 | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |     96 |
+-----------+--------+------+--------+----------+----------+---------+-------+
```

Please note that I am using a MySQL view. Views in MySQL **do not** allow **subqueries**.

**Edit:**

Based on prior suggestions, I have tried this:

```
SELECT a.player_id, a.europe, a.asia, a.africa, a.lamerica, a.namerica,    a.oceania, a.total 
FROM tbl AS a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT player_id, MAX(total) AS total 
    FROM tbl 
    GROUP BY player_id) b
ON a.player_id = b.player_id AND a.total = b.total
```

But I get these results:

```
+-----------+--------+------+--------+----------+----------+---------+-------+
| player_id | europe | asia | africa | lamerica | namerica | oceania | total |
+-----------+--------+------+--------+----------+----------+---------+-------+
|    121693 |   1076 | 70   | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |  1146 |
|    118840 |     40 | 490  | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |   530 |
|    121691 |     96 | NULL | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |   96  |
|    121691 |     96 | 0    | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    |    96 |
+-----------+--------+------+--------+----------+----------+---------+-------+
```

It also **returns a tie.**
*How is it possible to avoid this?*

Comment: I am interested to know why you thought `total AS total` was necessary

Comment: Sorry..I edited. I use MAX(total) as total

Comment: @Barmar: I edited the question. I tried to solutions posted in other similar questions but I couldn't get it work. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Add your attempt to use one of the solutions in the duplicate question. Then I can reopen and show how to correct it.

Comment: @Barmar: I updated with my attempt. Can you help me pls? Thanks.

Comment: As you can see I get player_id: 121691 two times because the total is the same. It should be only one.

Comment: @Barmar: Please reopen my question as it's different than the suggested solutions because in my case there is a tie in the max values. How could I eliminate the ties?

Comment: I've reopened it.

Comment: @dimoss What criteria should be used to break the ties? Add it to the subquery and the join.

Comment: @Barmar: There are not specific criteria. I just want to have only one and not all the ties. The data I gave here is a small piece. In the actual table there are a lot of ties. I want only one per 'player_id'. Thanks!

Comment: Add `group by a.player_id` at the very end. The contents of the other columns will be chosen arbitrarily from all the rows with ties. They might not come from the same rows as each other.

Answer (score 0):

Add another `GROUP BY a.player_id` to the query:

```
SELECT a.player_id, a.europe, a.asia, a.africa, a.lamerica, a.namerica,    a.oceania, a.total 
FROM tbl AS a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT player_id, MAX(total) AS total 
    FROM tbl 
    GROUP BY player_id) b
ON a.player_id = b.player_id AND a.total = b.total
GROUP BY a.player_id
```

This will select the contents of the other columns arbitrarily from the rows with ties.

If you have the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode enabled (it's on by default starting with MySQL 5.7) you'll need to use the `ANY_VALUE` to indicate that this is OK.

```
SELECT a.player_id, ANY_VALUE(a.europe), ANY_VALUE(a.asia), ANY_VALUE(a.africa), ANY_VALUE(a.lamerica), ANY_VALUE(a.namerica), ANY_VALUE(a.oceania), ANY_VALUE(a.total)
```